# How to use Tab in Latex?

Tags: paragraphs

For example:

```
If you don’t see this email in your inbox within If you don’t see this email in your inbox withinIf you don’t see this email in your inbox within
    - If you don’t see this email in your inbox within.If you don’t see this email 
      in your inbox within
    - If you don’t see this email in your inbox within.If you don’t see this email 
      in your inbox within
```

I had tried:

```
\begin{tabbing}
\> \> If you don’t see this email in youIf you don’t see this email in youIf you don’t see this email in you\\
\end{tabbing}
```

But it goes for a long time without going to second line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Thanks. Totally new today

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This remain me on list: `\begin{itemize}\item some longer text \item sn another longer text \end{itemize}`. Is this what you looking for?

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Is there any way to change the "." to "-"?

Comment: You seem to have a lot of very basic questions. The following might be of help: [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/11).  Also, Overleaf, which you are using, has lots of fairly good documentation here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Main_Page. You should also learn to read specific documentation for the packages that people recommend to you. See [How to find the documentation for a package?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/380019) for some ways to do this.

Answer (score 9):

I would *not* use the `tabbing` environment here. Instead, I would use an `itemize` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} % macros to modify appearance of 'itemize' environments

\begin{document}
If you don't see this email in your inbox within If you don't see this email in your inbox within. If you don't see this email in your inbox within
\begin{itemize}[nosep,label=\textendash] % 'nosep' makes for compact "look" of the list
\item If you don't see this email in your inbox within. If you don't see this email in your inbox within
\item If you don't see this email in your inbox within. If you don't see this email in your inbox within
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

You may ask, *why* use an `itemize` environment instead of a `tabbing` environment? It's because `itemize` environments are far more flexible and customizable. Using the more abstract `itemize` environment is also more in keeping with one of the core philosophies of LaTeX, which is to separate the *content* of the document from the formatting side of things. A `tabbing` environment comes close to applying visual formatting, which is (generally) frowned upon in LaTeX circles...

Comment: Thanks. What is the meaning of:
Latex Error: Can be used only in preamble
For the \begin{document}
\end{document}

Comment: @user193541 - Do you by any chance have `\usepackage` statements after `\begin{document}`? `\usepackage` statements are preamble-only directives...

Comment: Thanks, it works now.

Comment: @Mico In a few minutes we open the champagne :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano - Thsnks! :-) 73 more points to go...

Answer (score 5):

The answer is, of course use, `itemize`. But since this has been already explained, and the question show that you are a new user, and probably the use of that environment (specially in nested list) will be a little overwhelming for new users, worth to mention that there are options to make itemized lists in a simplified way. One is use the `markdown` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{markdown}
\def\labelitemi{\normalfont\bfseries{--}} % custom bullet 
\begin{document}
\begin{markdown}

- If you don’t see this email in your inbox within. If you don’t see this email in your inbox within    

- If you don’t see this email in your inbox within. If you don’t see this email in your inbox within    

\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

> [image: mwe1]

Note that within the `markdown` environment you are not writting LaTeX, but a different language that will be translated to LaTeX, so if you write `*italic*` will be internally translated to `\emph{italic}` and the output will be "*italic*", but writing directly `\emph{italic}` the output is simply "\emph{italic}". The bad news is that the markdow syntax is limited to a very basic format. The good new is that very easy, and when is not enough, you can end the environment and return to LaTeX syntax.

Alternatively, instead of `markdown` inside a LaTeX document, you can also write LaTeX inside a Rmarkdown document using Rstudio, without this limitation, so you can make a `test.Rmd` file with simply:

```
---
documentclass: article
classoption: twocolumn, a4paper
output:
  pdf_document: default
---

\def\labelitemi{\normalfont\bfseries{--}} <!-- custom bullet -->

- This document allows *italics*. 

- This document allows \emph{italics} and  and any other
  \fbox{\LaTeX} command.
```

This will translated to a `test.tex` document and then compiled to produce a `test.pdf`:

> [image: mwe2]